# How do I view the 8086 machine code of C and assembly programs?

Tags: c, x86-16, machine-code

I have a program in 8086 and C languages now i want to compare the machine code of each program. How can I get machine code of C and assembly 8086 code

I use `emu8086` and `DEV` .

Comment: Ermm ... C implementations don't use bytecode.  Bytecodes refer to instructions of a portable abstract machine (e.g. the JVM, Dalvik, CLI).  C tool chains compile to real machine code.  Please correct your question to clarify what you are actually asking here.

Comment: i changed my question.@stephenC

Comment: If it is your own ASM and C code you can get an assembly output from your C compiler and compare it with the ASM source code. But if you are trying to reverse-engineer somebody else's stuff, it's unlikely you'll get specific help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I get machine code of C and assembly 8086 code

Compile the C code using the standard compiler

Assemble the C code using the standard assembler

That gives you the machine code.

Then, assuming you are really wanting to *compare* the code ... :

- use a hex dump tool to look at / compare the two code files, or
- use a disassembler and compare the dissasembled versions of the C code with your original assembly code, or
- look up in your compiler documentation how to get it to output assembly language ...

Comment: Don't ask me to recommend specific tools.  That is off-topic, and I won't answer.

Comment: Sure, software recommendations are off-topic, but that doesn't mean you can't point to them in your answer. i.e, it wouldn't be off topic to mention `objdump`.

Comment: If you want write your own answer, please feel free.  However, I don't want any recommendations in my answer for the very same reason that that requests for recommendations are off-topic.  IMO, the OP is better off doing his own research.